# Change output for %cho%

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have coded a batch file that can do multiple things. Commands are entered from the main menu and are formatted like this:

```
echo Enter a command here:
:menucmd
set/p "cho=>"
if %cho%==latest goto 1.0.0
```

Each time I update the file I keep an update log within the batch file. After viewing the log, the user is taken to a menu like this:

```
 :loghome
    cls
    title Home
    echo Welcome back. What's next?
    echo You just viewed the (Filename) %cho% update log.
    echo Stuck? Type "help" for a list of things you can say.
    goto menucmd
```

The code that says:

```
echo You just viewed the (Filename) %cho% update log.
```

displays the previous command entered using %cho% from the main menu, which, in this case, is the name of the log previously viewed, unless the user has accessed the latest log using a command called "latest", in which case, the text says:

```
  echo You just viewed the (Filename) latest update log.
```

I would like to be able to insert some code into the update log which changes the output %cho% gives, so that the text says:

```
echo You just viewed the (Filename) 1.0.0 update log.
```

even if that is not what the user actually typed. What I am asking is, how do I change the output of "%cho%" without the user actually entering another command? Thank you.

Comment: 50% of the questions are poorly formatted in the remaining 50%, they are well formatted but poorly formulated. This is your case. I did not understand the scenario. Please, write down the current state of things and what should be changed in all its stages.

Comment: If I read between the lines, I understand that you want the "`latest`" become "`1.0.0`" Maybe something like this: `if "%cho%"=="latest" set "cho=1.0.0" &goto somewhere`

Answer (score 0):

The %cho% Variable can be used within a code to be replaced in an other name. I had no view on the :1.0.0 label and made a change for the safed Output to screen the loops Titel.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p "cho=>"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("%cho%") do set Variable=%%a
call :1.0.0
goto :eof

:1.0.0
for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%a in ("!Variable:%cho%=%0!") do (
call :logman %%a)
goto :eof

:logman
echo Welcome back. What's next?
echo You just viewed the (Filename) %1 update log
pause :: > nul
```

The delims delimiter option with the for loop in the :label Titel :1.0.0 substitutes the : double point symbol from the %cho% Output change to %0. The %0 Parameter shows the label Name.

For runtime changes setlocal enabledelayedexpansion for every !! is enabled.

The add a comment layout :: in the last line can be replaced.